# PUN 2.0 Camera renders for each player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, render

The main problem is to render a player body for every other player in a room. However, the player themself must see only attached hands, not his own body (and he must not see others attached hands). Is there a way to do this?

I tried to use a culling mask on cam, but it doesn't make a lot sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Culling mask actually make sense. Mark the body mesh with different layer should hide the body.

You just need to enable / disable it base on `isLocalPlayer` value.

Alternative way of doing this would be using two set prefebs.

- A. One is player controlled
- B. One for other player.

Where prefeb A only contains hands. But note that this come with other issue like player's body will not cast shadow as it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks,i just not enough familiar with PUN,that helped. Roman said almost the same,but i'm really thick

Answer (score 0):

I think using a culling mask makes perfect sense.

I'd use it in addition to disabling your own player mesh and enabling the attached hands if you have authority (if it's yours).

Comment: Well,when i'm loading a new player,he still can see another players hands. I thinking about creating layers runtime for every player,but i think there can be something more effective

Comment: No, I meant using the object's ownership to know when to hide hands of other players. Do not forget that multiplayer games are not identical copies of eachother, the game state is, but not necessarily the rendering (as you said, only the player sees his hands, but not the others').